# more accurately reproduce platform.sh NodeJS envs on local?

Tags: node.js, docker, platform.sh

Our team has a home-grown docker image, but too many details slip through the cracks. We've not successfully covered all the bases quite yet.

Does anyone have a setup (DDEV or similar would be particularly useful) to match Platform.sh NodeJS environments accurately? If so, a few high-level instructions along those lines would help.

The ideal would be to have our whole team's local development environment match exactly to our Platform.sh environments. We seem to have good success using DDEV with PHP so far, so extending that success would be a win.

Answer (score 0):

PSH Support has provided the start of an answer. Here's a summary of the info shared:

- The `nodejs:14` image is built from LTS releases of Debian. The current release is [Debian 9 "Stretch"](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). There are some differences, but it's a pretty good match.
- A need to update libraries, including one that broke on a project of ours, may prompt a switch "down the road" to Debian 10 “Buster”.
- Determine the version used in your container by connecting with ssh then `$ cat /etc/debian_version`.

An observation: our PHP@7 environments also use Debian 9 "Stretch"